# Prevent React from re-drawing every time mouse position is updated?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html5-canvas

I've been working on a project for fun where I want to have a couple of different eyes bouncing around a screen. I want the pupil of the eye to follow the user's mouse as it moves around the page. In order to accomplish this, I planned to add an eventlistener for mousemove and update state every time the position is updated.

However, I have found that the state update triggers a re-run of my useEffect for drawing the canvas. *This causes the appearance that the ball moves faster when the user is moving their mouse.* I was wondering if anyone has any advice on how to avoid this or how to better organize my code to get around this issue?

You can use the "Console" tab in the sandbox to see log statements that occur during unintended updates.

```
const draw = (ctx: CanvasRenderingContext2D, mousePos: {x: number, y: number}) => {
  ctx.canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
  ctx.canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
  bubbles.forEach((bubble, index) => {
    bubble.intersectWall();
    bubble.move();
    bubble.draw(mousePos);
  });
};

const handleMouseMove = (e: MouseEvent) => {
  setMousePos({ x: e.screenX, y: e.screenY });
};

// Initialize bubbles on page load
useEffect(() => {
  const canvas = canvasRef.current as HTMLCanvasElement;
  const context = canvas.getContext("2d") as CanvasRenderingContext2D;

  window.addEventListener("mousemove", handleMouseMove);

  const initBubbles = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
    initBubbles.push(
      new Bubble(
        randomNumber(0 + BUBBLE_RADIUS, window.innerWidth - BUBBLE_RADIUS),
        randomNumber(0 + BUBBLE_RADIUS, window.innerHeight - BUBBLE_RADIUS),
        randomNumber(-1, 4),
        randomNumber(-4, 4),
        context
      )
    );
  }
  setBubbles(initBubbles);
  return () => {
    window.removeEventListener("mousemove", handleMouseMove);
  };
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
  const canvas = canvasRef.current as HTMLCanvasElement;
  const context = canvas.getContext("2d") as CanvasRenderingContext2D;
  let animationFrameId: number;

  const render = () => {
    draw(context, mousePos);
    animationFrameId = window.requestAnimationFrame(render);
  };
  render();

  return () => {
    window.cancelAnimationFrame(animationFrameId);
  };
}, [draw]);
```

Codepen example: https://codepen.io/pietrofan12/pen/wvEBPPx

Thank you in advance and sorry for bad english

Comment: Your useEffect callback has draw as the second parameter. This means that it will be called every time that draw variable is updated or called. In your useEffect call, you also have it calling the draw function. This will lead to it recursively calling.

Comment: Yes this is desired functionality, as I want to be constantly redrawing the ball and moving it. The problem appear when I also update the mouse position, as this calls useEffect when mouse position updates but I don't want this

Comment: Your example would be more helpful if you used `console.log()` to help us understand intended versus unintended updates

Comment: @Slbox I added this to codepen, it is just when mouse moves and the ball has appearance that speed increases

Comment: I agree with @Slbox, I am still unclear what the question is asking and what your desired functionality is. If you find an example of what you want, please link it.

Comment: @needhelpplease123 your new sandbox and explanation are a big improvement. Thanks!